# Provide location information (GPS) for Android in Anbox

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, location

I want to run Osmand on Anbox on Odroid N2 and I am nearly there. The part I am stuck on is getting location to work. I see there is something called ["Goldfish GPS Module"](https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/goldfish/+/refs/heads/nougat-mr2-release/gps/gps_qemu.c) and indeed in my Android installation I can see /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so Now, this module seems to communicate over channel named "gps". The question is how do I actually provide any data to it? Or to put it in other words: where is the other end of the channel? How do I provide any data to it either real (from hardware GPS module) or fake? Or maybe I should be using another way altogether?

Comment: Running into the same issue. Did you figure out a way?

Comment: I made pull request to provide location to anbox and it was accepted.